# Combination of 2 group of objects in a particular way.

Tags: permutations, combinations, factorial

I'm a newbie. So the question is to arrange a objects and b such that it stays in order `a and then b`.

So what I think the answer is `(a! * b!)/((a+b)!)`.

If that is right how can I simplify it further to a small formula to compute with computer ?

If I'm wrong please guide me.

Comment: Very simple. Picture the two groups a and b as blocks; of course a has to come before b. Then you can arrange the objects in a in a! ways, and the objects in b in b! ways. Multiply and you get a!b!.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel thanks. So did I calculate the probability of particular arrangement out of total arrangements?

Comment: That's only the number of ways. To get the probability out of all arrangements, note that all the objects can be arranged in (a+b)! ways, so the answer is a!b!/(a+b)!.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel thanks. See my original post. That's the probability, right ?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: Is there way to minimise this formula ? I mean if I were to write a program calculating so many big factorial would be a problem. So is there a way out of it ?

Comment: Three factorials is already a small enough number. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks a lot.